# Creating a dropdown in Flutter using a Json list

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-web

I am getting a Json list from an API and trying to put it into a dropdown for the users to select their customer.

Json File

```js
import 'dart:convert';

CustomerJson welcomeFromJson(String str) =>
    CustomerJson.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(CustomerJson data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CustomerJson {
  CustomerJson({
    this.customer,
    this.salesRep,
    this.userValues,
    this.terms,
    this.type,
    this.shipVia,
    this.salesCode,
    this.taxCode,
    this.name,
    this.emailAddress,
    this.url,
    this.status,
    this.shipLeadDays,
    this.printStatement,
    this.creditLimit,
    this.currBalance,
    // this.customerSince,
    this.acceptBo,
    this.pricingLevel,
    this.partner,
    this.currencyDef,
    this.noteText,
    this.lastUpdated,
    this.taxId,
    this.acctMgr,
    this.rating,
    this.qBId,
    this.psTId,
    this.sendReportByEmail,
    this.creditApproved,
    this.creditApprovedBy,
    this.creditApprovedDate,
  });

  String? customer;
  String? salesRep;
  int? userValues;
  String? terms;
  String? type;
  String? shipVia;
  dynamic salesCode;
  dynamic taxCode;
  String? name;
  dynamic emailAddress;
  dynamic url;
  String? status;
  int? shipLeadDays;
  bool? printStatement;
  int? creditLimit;
  double? currBalance;
  // DateTime? customerSince;
  bool? acceptBo;
  dynamic pricingLevel;
  dynamic partner;
  int? currencyDef;
  dynamic noteText;
  DateTime? lastUpdated;
  dynamic taxId;
  String? acctMgr;
  int? rating;
  dynamic qBId;
  dynamic psTId;
  bool? sendReportByEmail;
  bool? creditApproved;
  dynamic creditApprovedBy;
  dynamic creditApprovedDate;

  factory CustomerJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CustomerJson(
        customer: json["customer"],
        salesRep: json["sales_Rep"],
        userValues: json["user_Values"],
        terms: json["terms"],
        type: json["type"],
        shipVia: json["ship_Via"],
        salesCode: json["sales_Code"],
        taxCode: json["tax_Code"],
        name: json["name"],
        emailAddress: json["email_Address"],
        url: json["url"],
        status: json["status"],
        shipLeadDays: json["ship_Lead_Days"],
        printStatement: json["print_Statement"],
        creditLimit: json["credit_Limit"],
        currBalance: json["curr_Balance"],
        // customerSince: DateTime.parse(json["customer_Since"]),
        acceptBo: json["accept_BO"],
        pricingLevel: json["pricing_Level"],
        partner: json["partner"],
        currencyDef: json["currency_Def"],
        noteText: json["note_Text"],
        lastUpdated: DateTime.parse(json["last_Updated"]),
        taxId: json["tax_ID"],
        acctMgr: json["acct_Mgr"],
        rating: json["rating"],
        qBId: json["qB_ID"],
        psTId: json["psT_ID"],
        sendReportByEmail: json["send_Report_By_Email"],
        creditApproved: json["credit_Approved"],
        creditApprovedBy: json["credit_Approved_By"],
        creditApprovedDate: json["credit_Approved_Date"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "customer": customer,
        "sales_Rep": salesRep,
        "user_Values": userValues,
        "terms": terms,
        "type": type,
        "ship_Via": shipVia,
        "sales_Code": salesCode,
        "tax_Code": taxCode,
        "name": name,
        "email_Address": emailAddress,
        "url": url,
        "status": status,
        "ship_Lead_Days": shipLeadDays,
        "print_Statement": printStatement,
        "credit_Limit": creditLimit,
        "curr_Balance": currBalance,
        // "customer_Since": customerSince?.toIso8601String(),
        "accept_BO": acceptBo,
        "pricing_Level": pricingLevel,
        "partner": partner,
        "currency_Def": currencyDef,
        "note_Text": noteText,
        "last_Updated": lastUpdated?.toIso8601String(),
        "tax_ID": taxId,
        "acct_Mgr": acctMgr,
        "rating": rating,
        "qB_ID": qBId,
        "psT_ID": psTId,
        "send_Report_By_Email": sendReportByEmail,
        "credit_Approved": creditApproved,
        "credit_Approved_By": creditApprovedBy,
        "credit_Approved_Date": creditApprovedDate,
      };
}
```

API Call

```js
Future<List<CustomerJson>?> GetCustomerIDsCall(String APIKey) async {
 var headers = {'APIKey': APIKey};
  var request = http.Request(
      'GET',
      Uri.parse(
          'http://65.254.144.50:5114/Customers'));

  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  final response = await request.send();
  final String respStr = await response.stream.bytesToString();
  final responseList = json.decode(respStr) as List;

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    CustomerIDs =
        responseList.map((Customer) => CustomerJson.fromJson(Customer)).toList();
    return (CustomerIDs);
  } else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
}
```

DropdownButton Call

```js
   Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
           child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
             child: DropdownButton<dynamic>(
            value: CustomerID_value ?? CustomerIDs[0],
            hint: Text('Customer ID'),
            items: CustomerIDs.map<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>((value) => DropdownMenuItem(value: value,child: Text('${value["customer"]}'),)).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) => setState(() => CustomerID_value = value),
          ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

The Json file and API works as I am getting the information from it in another part of the program. I am just not sure as to what I am supposed to do with the Json List(CustomerIDs) to allow the dropdownbutton to read what I need to then display it. I need to display CustomerIDs.customer within the dropdownbutton for users to select what customer they with to use within the form.

CustomerID_value Initialization

```js
class CreateUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CreateUser> createState() => _CreateUserState();
}

class _CreateUserState extends State<CreateUser> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final customerIDController = TextEditingController();
  final roleController = TextEditingController();
  final activityController = TextEditingController();
  String? status_value;
  ***String? CustomerID_value;***
  String? role_value;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    customerIDController.dispose();
    roleController.dispose();
    activityController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }
```

CustomerIDs Initialization

```js
late var CustomerIDs;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can customize with items property of dropdown.

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: DropdownButton<dynamic>(
        value: CustomerID_value ?? CustomerIDs[0],
        hint: Text('Customer ID'),
        items: CustomerIDs.map<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>(
            (value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: value,
                child: Text('${value["customer"]}'),
                      )).toList(),
        onChanged: (value) => setState(() => CustomerID_value = value)))
```

Comment: This did not work. This is my new Items portion after that answer                                  items: CustomerIDs.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((value) => DropdownMenuItem(value: value['customer'],child: Text(value['customer']),)).toList(),
onChanged: (value) => setState(() => this.CustomerID_value = value as String?),                     I am now receiving the error:                                                                                      
Expected a value of type '(CustomerJson) => DropdownMenuItem<String>', but got one of type '(dynamic) => DropdownMenuItem<Object>'

Comment: what do you want to select on change? is the whole object or just the customer. there is type mismatch between declared and selection. you can rectify it know? edited the answer. try that

Comment: This also is not working. now I am getting error: NoSuchMethodError: '[]' as for your question of what I want to select. I would like to just select the Customer in the Json list and print them within the dropdown.

Comment: check the updated one. it should work

Comment: I am still gettting Error: NoSuchMethodError: '[]' After changing everything to exactly what the answer states. I will say that for some reason the .map doesn't have a color like everything else does and I am not sure if that is what is causing the possible issue it that it can't be mapped for some reason?

Comment: update the question with how the variables like Customer_value and CustomerIDs are declared and intialised.

Comment: The question has been updated with the variables declaration and initialization, While also updating the new dropdown method

Comment: your Customer_value is a string but in the dropdown, it is been used as an object. Either change the declaration as an object or in the dropdown value access string. That is why I asked if you need to select the entire object onchange or just the customer value inside the object.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out by just creating a list of classes and iterating through the json list implementing each item into the regular list and that worked.